How to use the "localize" option on starting localization from a saved map, Slam_toolbox
Using ROS2 Jazzy. I've gotten to the point where I can map a room, serialize and save that map and launch it in the localization mode. Currently I am using the "start at dock" option for initializing the position of the robot, but in the SlamTooboxPlugin for rviz, I see this option called "localize", presumably for startup as well.  If this does what I imagine, which is localize the robot on startup without giving it the exact start pose, how would I implement this. I can't find any mention of this in the documentation or questions. Any help would be appreciated!

I don't understand the question - can you be specific about what you want to do?

@SteveMacenski I'm asking if this option does anything, if I need to do something specific to implement it, or if there is another way to accomplish the goal. That being, upon launching slam_toolbox in localization mode using the localization executable, attempting to localize the position of the robot on said saved map based on the current sensor data, without providing it a starting pose.
Currently, my localization assumes that I am starting at the dock every time, I'm asking if there is an option to localize the robot elsewhere, such as in the case of an unexpected restart?

If you're not starting at the dock, you can start at the start at estimated pose option
